# How to read session variable in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an image hyperlinked as:

```
<a id="register" href = "javascript:void(0)"
data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="<cms:show my_image_thumb />" alt="" class="fade"></a>
```

I have a `getsession.php` class to get the session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
    echo "1";
else
echo "0";
?>
```

I want to read the session variable value on click of the image. I am trying to do this as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#register").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
        url:'getsession.php',
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            // Do something with the result
            if(data=="1"){
             window.location = "www.google.com";
            }else{
             document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
             document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
             document.getElementById('fade').scrollIntoView(true); 
            }
          }
        });
     });
   });
</script>
```

However, when clicking the image there is no effect. Any pointers?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: and if is not set `$_SESSION`? you are not returning anything

Comment: @Cheshire adding that doesnt solve either

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to log ( `console.log('button clicked');` ) that the function is entered and then log the data  ( `console.log(data);` ) when the response arrives.

Also, check that the php script is working by simply opening it in the browser.

By the way, `window.location` should have an absolute url assigned to it

`window.location = "http://www.google.com";`

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your php file is not placed in the proper position. Try running the file directly from url. It should print 1 if session is set. And after this,try changing the url to absolute url of the file like `http://localhost/getsession.php`  .

Comment: I did run the file directly and it loads a blank page. There is nothing. What does that mean?

Comment: Try putting the else part in the getsession.php and print 0 in that. Then run.

Comment: I did add the else part. It gives 0 now. However, there is no effect on clicking the image

Comment: try adding full path in url field of ajax call like this [link]http://localhost/getsession.php as mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yes I already have added the full path. Still on clicking the image there is no effect

Comment: You have added class to the image fade not id as you are referring to the id. Change that and then try.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what was the issue. But how come I cannot refer to the click event through the id?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I cannot refer to the click event through the id' ??

Comment: what I mean is that when I  have `$("#idname").click(function(){` it doesnt work, when I have `$(".classname").click(function(){` it works.

Comment: It usually happens when the id is assigned to more than one elements and you try to call an event on second/third or so on elements. event attached to id only works for the first element with that id. Hope you understand, what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
    echo "1";
  else
    echo "0";
?>
```

js:

```
   $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/getsession.php',
        cache:false,
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){
            // Do something with the result
            alert("ajax call success returns: "+ data);
            if(data=="1"){
             window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
            }else{
             window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";
            }
        },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error Code: " + jqXHR.status + ", Type:" + textStatus + ", Message: " + errorThrown);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I ran the file getsession.php on the browser directly and it is returning `0`. However, modifying my code as you siggested has no effect on clicking the image. Any pointers?

Comment: No I did not get any alert (error). On clicking has no effect at all. Is the function getting called at all? How do i verify?